# c# my resource text file comes up with different Encoding when I read it with Streamreader

Tags: c#, .net, resources

Here is the code that I am using to take text from my resource.rex and after that, I collect them on Listbox and then take one of them with a random method but some words show up like '?' I think their encoding changes after reading.

```cs
string okunanmetin = "";

Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Takistoskop.Resources.5.txt"),Encoding.UTF8);

int i = 0;
while (true)
{
    i++;    
    okunanmetin = reader.ReadLine();
    if (okunanmetin == null) break;
    listBoxcekilenveri.Items.Add(" " + okunanmetin + "\r\n");
}
```

Comment: is your file actually utf8 encoded?

Comment: I think yes because I create text file in resource and then paste my text into it and the new text file's settings is unicode utf-8

Comment: You can check or change encoding of your text file using Notepad++ using menu 'Encoding'